# Software that can mass expand adf.ly URLs

Tags: url, url-shortening

I need software that can mass (not one by one) expand shortened [AdFly](http://adf.ly/) URLs.

I’ve tried http://urlex.org/ but it failed.

Answer (score 1):

[FreeRapid Downloader](http://wordrider.net/freerapid) can mass-expand adf.ly urls.
After adding the adf.ly urls, just right click the list and then copy URLs.

Comment: Do you know of an online service that can do this too? I don't run Windows and running a virtual machine just to expand one or two links would be an overkill.

Comment: i don't run windows too.. it's java-based..